# Including files on local files without server

Tags: javascript, html, include

I'm making quick prototypes and would like to include files. Usually I put things on a server and use PHP (or whatever) to include files (header, nav, bodyMain, bodySec). Now I don't have that option. iFrames are such a poor substitute that I would rather keep everything in one file.

Is there any way to use jquery's load() and somehow pass something to avoid the "'Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error?

Again - there are no server options here, no IIS nor Apache options.

Is there any workaround - or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in the general case. Some browsers allow you to disable security at load time (usually with command line switches).

You'd really be better off getting a webserver. There are some very simple ones that will run without any special privileges (on a high numbered port). I tend to use [http_this](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-HTTPThis/bin/http_this) and use PerlBrew to install it in my home directory.

Comment: thx. will take a look at it. If I can put it on the shared drive it would be a godsend.

Comment: I'm prevented from installing this at work. So be it. But it looks perfect.